# How to force ffmpeg into non-interactive mode?

Tags: ffmpeg, stdin, interactive, non-interactive

Sometimes you want ffmpeg to ask you whether it should overwrite a file. Sometimes it's just a script that you prefer would fail if something is amiss. I.e. don't rely on stdin to answer if you have a question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options

`-stdin` -
Enable interaction on standard input. On by default unless a pipe is detected.

`-nostdin` - To explicitly disable console interactions. Without `-y` this will cause ffmpeg to error out if the target file exists.

`-y` - To overwrite the output file

Comment: That's if you want it to always overwrite. If you'd rather it error out then `-nostdin` is the right option.

Comment: @slhck, `-y` is not enough. FFmpeg is still eating some characters which is causing weird bugs in the shell scripts.

Comment: You appear to need -nostdin -y
In order to overwrite

Comment: running this inside a bash script and calling the script from command line, ffmpeg still outputs to terminal

Comment: @Freedo if you want to redirect the output you can always use the shell redirect `ffmpeg ... > output.log 2>&1` (the `2>&1` is if you want errors to also go to that log file).